# Jquery fadeIn is fading 2 divs in at once

Tags: jquery, css, fadein

For the page I'm working on, I have 4 hidden divs which can each be faded in on click with Jquery. For some reason when I click on one of the divs it fades in, but also fades in one of the other divs as well. This does not happen if I try fading the other div in 1st. Any guesses why? You can see what I mean here http://www.unearthingfilm.com/optimized.html

If you go to the menu item and hit storytellers and click on the book, the div fades in, but so does the one below it further down

```
trigger3.click(function () {
        openBook.fadeIn(1000);
        closed.delay(1000).fadeIn('slow')
    });
    closed.click(function () {
        openBook.delay(700).fadeOut('slow');
    });


    trigger4.click(function () {
        openChest.fadeIn('slow');
    });


#openChest{
    background-image: url(../images/openChest.png);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 640px;
    width: 574px;
    top:4650px;
    left:250px;
    display:none;
}
#openBook{
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    height: 542px;
    width: 950px;
    left: 25px;
    top: 3300px;
    z-index:11;
    background-image: url(../images/openBook.png);
    }
```

Comment: May you show some of the HTML? Often times this happens when the target `div`s are nested (on purpose or accident)

Comment: I'm not completely sure without seeing your html, but try stopping event bubbling using `event.stopPropagation()` in your `click` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your source you're doing this:

`var trigger1, trigger2, trigger3, trigger4 = $('#trigger1, #trigger2, #trigger3, #trigger4')`

this only set's `trigger4` to  `$('#trigger1, #trigger2, #trigger3, #trigger4')`, the rest of the vars are not initialized.

Comment: Yes you are right. That was on overseen variable I had set for some animations I took out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've defined openBook as a var somewhere, your jQuery should look like this:

```
$('#openBook').fadeIn();
```

I'm not sure exactly why, but by not properly stating your selectors jQuery is getting confused. The same goes for all selectors in the code you've shown.

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/